# Accessing the width of an image using jquery

Tags: jquery, width

I'm taking an online class that is using the below code to get the width of images in an unordered list.  All this function returns for me is the code of the jQuery function itself, not the pixel number.

```
$("#slider ul li img").first().width;
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Has jQuery for some reason altered the width code since the lesson I'm taking was posted?

I've tried everything I can think of, which isn't much considering how short the code is.

Comment: Typo?  If `width` is a function then you forgot the parentheses to invoke it...

Comment: Thanks for the help!  That definitely worked